# AutorowSorter in Jtable linked to mysql

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I am trying to populate a `jtable` from Mysql through `defaultTableModel`.
I get the data and show in `jTable`, I delete and update the rows from `jTable` and they get deleted and updated in Mysql.

Now I need to implement sorting and filtering. For sorting I used `setautoCreateRowSorter`, it works on the `jTable` but it delete different recoreds from Mysql.

I tried to use `convertRowIndexToModel` in hope that it might resolve the problem but it didn't. It didn't give any error but didn't resolve the issue.

Now kindly help me to do something so when I delete or update my selected row in `jTable`, it should delete or update the corresponding row in Mysql.

thanks..

Comment: can u post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setautoCreateRowSorter, it works on the jTable but it delete different recoreds from Mysql. I tried to use convertRowIndexToModel in hope that it might resolve the problem but it didn't. It didn't give any error but didn't resolve the issue.

To remove a row from the model you would need to use the `convertRowIndexToModel()` so you delete the proper row in the model.

To remove the row from the database you use the data from the table because all the data is in the view of the table. So you just use the row index without any conversion. That means you use `table.getValueAt(...)` to get the data for the row to be deleted.

It is then up to you to create the proper SQL delete command. We don't know the structure of your database so we can't tell you what the SQL should be. That is we don't know what the key to your table is or what column in the table represents that key.

Comment: I used converRowIndexToModel() everywhere to update, delete and add, now it's working fine in my jtable as well as in Mysql. Now I want to add a filter to this jTable with a jTextField. Would that be possible with DefualtTableModel ??

Comment: Filtering works with any `TableModel`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Well, In this example, they are doing the filtering through AbstractTableModel and that was my question at the first place to somehow do it by using defualtTableModel because I have already created code to add, update and delete rows. If I shift to AbstractTableModel, I'll have to change a lot of things.. :(

Comment: @MahadRafique, No they are not doing the filtering through AbstractTableModel. Do you know what "abstract" means?